# PowerShell string default parameter value does not work as expected

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

```
#Requires -Version 2.0

[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
  [Parameter()] [string] $MyParam = $null
)

if($MyParam -eq $null) {
  Write-Host 'works'
} else {
  Write-Host 'does not work'
}
```

Outputs "does not work" => looks like strings are converted from null to empty string implicitly? Why? And how to test if a string is empty or really $null? This should be two different values!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Okay, found the answer @ https://www.codykonior.com/2013/10/17/checking-for-null-in-powershell/

Assuming:

```
Param(
  [string] $stringParam = $null
)
```

And the parameter was not specified (is using default value):

```
# will NOT work
if ($null -eq $stringParam)
{
}

# WILL work:
if ($stringParam -eq "" -and $stringParam -eq [String]::Empty)
{
}
```

Alternatively, you can specify a special null type:

```
Param(
  [string] $stringParam = [System.Management.Automation.Language.NullString]::Value
)
```

In which case the `$null -eq $stringParam` will work as expected.

Weird!

Comment: Please note that in PowerShell you should really use `if ($null -eq $value)` instead of `if ($value -eq $null)`. The PowerShell Script Analyser module warns for this as well. See https://www.spcaf.com/blog/powershell-null-comparison/

Comment: Or better yet `if ([String::IsNullOrEmpty($stringParam)])`, which changes the behavior slightly (for the better imo), but reads nicely and eliminates the issue of order.  Regardless, thanks, this helped me a ton.

Answer (score 14):

You will need to use the `AllowNull` attribute if you want to allow `$null` for string parameters:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param (
    [Parameter()] 
    [AllowNull()]
    [string] $MyParam
)
```

And note that you [should use $null on the left-hand side of the comparison](https://www.spcaf.com/blog/powershell-null-comparison/):

```
if ($null -eq $MyParam)
```

if you want it to work predictably

Answer (score 3):

seeing many equality comparisons with [String]::Empty, you could use the [String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace or [String]::IsNullOrEmpty static methods, like the following:

```
param(
    [string]$parameter = $null
)

# we know this is false
($null -eq $parameter)

[String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($parameter)
[String]::IsNullOrEmpty($parameter)
('' -eq $parameter)
("" -eq $parameter)
```

which yields:

```
PS C:\...> .\foo.ps1
False
True
True
True
True
```

Comment: This answer doesn't really address any of the remarks in the question (ie. explanation of the behavior when assigning `$null` to a `[string]` parameter)

Comment: I thought I answered the question: "And how to test if a string is empty or really $null?"

Answer (score 3):

Simply do *not* declare the param's type if you want a $null value to remain:

```
Param(
    $stringParam
)
```

(None of the other solutions worked for me when declaring the type.)

Comment: Switch to javascript-style declaration and comparison when it comes to strings I suppose (unfortunately).  All the rest of this post seems to reflect powershell baggage.

Answer (score 1):

So it seems a default value of `$null` for parameters of type `[string]`  defaults to empty string, for whatever reason.

Option 1

```
if ($stringParam) { ... }
```

Option 2

```
if ($stringParam -eq "") { ... }
```

Option 3

```
if ($stringParam -eq [String]::Empty) { ... }
```

Comment: For not assigned I would prefer `If (-not $stringParam) { ... }`