# Optional String Parameter (should be NULL)

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I try to introduce an optional string parameter to my function. [Based on this thread should](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22906520/powershell-string-default-parameter-value-does-not-work-as-expected) `[AllowNull()]` do the trick, but PowerShell still populates my parameter with an empty string (using PowerShell version 5.1.14393.206).

The following function illustrates the problem:

```
function Test-HowToManageOptionsStringParameters() {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [int] $MandatoryParameter,
        [Parameter()]
        [AllowNull()]
        [string] $OptionalStringParameter = $null
    )

    if ($null -eq $OptionalStringParameter) {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green 'This works as expected';
    } else {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red 'Damit - Parameter should be NULL';
    }
}
```

To makes think even worse is even this code not working (assigning `$null` to the parameter for testing), I really do not understand why this is not working…

```
function Test-HowToManageOptionsStringParameters() {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [int] $MandatoryParameter,
        [Parameter()]
        [AllowNull()]
        [string] $OptionalStringParameter = $null
    )

    $OptionalStringParameter = $null;

    if ($null -eq $OptionalStringParameter) {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green 'This works as expected';
    } else {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red 'Damit - Parameter should be NULL';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) is assigning an empty string to your variable if you assign it to `$null` **if** its declared as a `[string]`.

You can get arround it by *omiting* the type `[string]` on `$OptionalStringParameter`. Another way would be to check for `[string]::IsNullOrEmpty($OptionalStringParameter)` within your if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
function Test-HowToManageOptionsStringParameters() {
PARAM(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [int] $MandatoryParameter,
    [Parameter()]
    [AllowNull()]
    [string] $OptionalStringParameter
)

if(-not $OptionalStringParameter) {
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green 'This works as expected';
}
else {
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red 'Damit - Parameter should be NULL';
}
}
```

Use either `!` or the `-not` operator to check for null. If think the problem is that you've a *typed* parameter -> you find an explanation in the comments of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29724851/empty-parameter-is-not-null-in-function).

Hope that helps